# Kibana4 to listen on Port 80 instead of Port 5601

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, kibana-4

I have elasticsearch 1.4 and kibana4 running on an Amazo EC2 instance running RHEL7.

Kibana4 is running as a standalone process and is not deployed in a web container such as nginx.It is listening on Port 5601.(the default port). I would like to have kibana listen on port 80.

Can this be achieved without using nginx? If yes how?

Comment: just check the config file, it probably has a setting of the port

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit file {kibana-directory}/config/kibana.yml. Find this line:

```
port: 5601
```

and change it to:

```
port: 80
```

Comment: In Kibana 4 you can do that w/o privileged user. You will get error such

`FATAL { [Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80]`

Comment: where Can I find {kibana-directory}/config/kibana.yml.

Comment: Programs without root privilege can NOT listen to ports under 1000 on unix systems

Answer (score 7):

You need to set capabilities `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` to bind non root process to a privileged port (<1024)

to make kibana listen on port 80 :

1- edit kibana port in /etc/kibana/kibana.yml

```
server.port : "80"
```

2- run the following commands :

```
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+epi /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+epi /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana-plugin
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+epi /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana-keystore
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+epi /usr/share/kibana/node/bin/node
```

Comment: For more context, see [Kibana unable to bind port 80 or 443](https://openthreat.ro/kibana-unable-to-bind-port-80-or-443/).

Answer (score 1):

Setting the port 80 in config file will trigger the following error
`kibana[11777]:  FATAL  Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80`
due to the fact that kibana service by default executes under the user kibana

You can change the user to root, but this will trigger the following warning
`kibana[11639]: Kibana should not be run as root.  Use --allow-root to continue.`

So running kibana service under root user is something not recommended. Better make a port forwarding rule, or a HTTP redirect if you have a web server.

Answer (score 0):

Full settings here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html

This should be added to config/kibana.yml 
server.port: 80

And run kibana server with sudo. Make sure no process is using port 80 at the same time.

Comment: Running a service as sudo is never a good idea.
Instead, you can give it permissions to listen in a lower port (>1024).
`sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+epi path/to/exec` (like /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana or java or...)