# How can I take upload the docker Image into Github

Tags: image, docker, docker-compose, kibana

I wanted to use Kibana docker image.

Below is the docker-compose that I am using.

```
kibana:
    image: kibana
    links:
      - "elasticsearch"
    ports:
      - "9201:9201"
    networks:
      - cloud
```

This image gets run on **5601** though I am specifying  **9201**

[image]
 I learn about changing the Port for Kibana [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615310/kibana4-to-listen-on-port-80-instead-of-port-5601)

If I do so every time I run the container using `docker-compose up` it will pull the latest image.

As a reason, I want to put this docker Image into VSTS/GIT so that I can modify the content there and use it.

**I don't want just a docker image. I want the configuration of it which I can change as per my requirement.**

Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so, you meant you want to learn how to use git?

Comment: No, I want to store the docker image for kibana into some-place So that I can modify its kibana.yml and use it.

Answer (score 0):

The docker image is a base from which the container is created. When you run `docker-compose up` docker-compose will use the docker engine to start all the services that you have specified in the compose.yml file.
If the containers do not exist, it will create new ones and if they do exist, it will start your running containers.
The YML file (docker-compose.yml) can be uploaded to whichever repository you wish, but if you wish to upload a image, you will have to use a docker registry.

This is probably not really what you wish to do. You should rather store all your configurations in a mounted directory which is actually on the computer running the docker containers instead of in the image or container itself.
You could also create a docker volume which you store the configuration in, it will persist as long as you do not remove it.

Now, when it comes to the port issue, you are binding the containers `9201` to your `9201`, if the service in the container is not running on `9201` you will not be able to reach it through that port.
Port mapping is done with `host:container`, so if you want to bind your computers `9201` to the containers `5601` you write:

```
ports:
  - "9201:5601"
```

And it should map 5601 to 9201.

Comment: I have already configure `ports:
  - "9201:5601" ` But didnt work. I have also try to implement docker volume but i am getting `docker volume error FATAL CLI ERROR Error`

Comment: I know the concept of DTR. I was just curious if we modify the content of existing Docker images. Like kibana is the docker image provided by docker we don't have the source code of it more precisely `kibana.yml`.

Comment: You can change the container and use the `commit` command to save the changes to a image. Then you can upload it to a docker registry.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/